# Usual arithmetic conversions in C : Whats the rationale behind this particular rule

Tags: c, integer-promotion

From k&R C

> - First,  if  either  operand  is  long  double,  the  other  is  converted  to  long  double.
> - Otherwise,  if  either  operand  is  double,  the  other  is  converted  to  double.
> - Otherwise,  if  either  operand  is  float,  the  other  is  converted  to  float.
> - *Otherwise, the integral promotions are performed on both operands*;
>     ...

This would mean below expression

```
char a,b,c;

c=a+b;
```

is actually caculated as

```
c = char((int)a+(int)b);
```

What is the rationale behind this rule?

Do these conversions happen if a, b and c were short ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No that's not actually true. C99 Section `5.1.2.3 Program execution`, clause 10 covers *exactly* the case you ask about:

> EXAMPLE 2
>   In executing the fragment
>   `char c1, c2;`
>   `c1 = c1 + c2;`
>   the "integer promotions" require that the abstract machine promote the value of each variable to int size and then add the two ints and truncate the sum.
>
> Provided the addition of two chars can be done without overflow, or with overflow wrapping silently to produce the correct result, the actual execution need only produce the same result, possibly omitting the promotions.

So, if the operation is known to produce the same result, there's no requirement for using the wider values.

But if you want the rationale behind a specific decision made in the standard, you have to look at, ..... wait for it, ..... yes, the [Rationale document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) :-)

In section 6.3.1.8 of that rationale (sections match those in the standard), it states:

> Explicit license was added to perform calculations in a “wider” type than absolutely necessary, since this can sometimes produce smaller and faster code, not to mention the correct answer more often.
>
> Calculations can also be performed in a “narrower” type by the as if rule so long as the same end result is obtained.

Comment: So as long as Implementation ensures 'char((int)a+(int)b)' and 'a+b' are same promotions can be omitted ?

Comment: It should be mentioned that the cited part of the standard covers program flow and possible optimizations. It is always best to assume that integer promotion takes place, or you might end up with bugs. Take for example `(c1+c2) / c3` where c1+c2 might overflow. The compiler can't optimize away the promotion there, as it would give a different result.

Answer (score 2):

Several instruction set architectures do not have any arithmetic machine instructions to operate on less-than-a-word integers (like `short` and `char`). So requiring that convention makes thing simpler for the compiler. And most of the time, converting to word and operating on word-sized operands is enough.

Answer (score 1):

> Do these conversions happen if a, b and c were short ?

Yes, integer promotions are done on all small integer types: char, short and C99 bool.

Strictly speaking, a C program cannot perform any form of arithmetic on anything smaller than an `int`, unless the compiler optimizes away the integer promotions.

Comment: Out of curiosity: have you ever seen a compiler which (incorrectly) optimizes away the integer promotions?

Comment: @pmor Optimizing away - sure. Incorrectly, no. It may however optimize code taking implicit promotion in account, such as optimizing `uint8_t u8=0xAA; u8 = ~u8 >> 4;` into pure 8 bit instructions but still resulting in `0xF5`. An incorrect optimization would be to carry out the `~u8` with an 8 bit instruction giving the result `0x55` then shifting into end result `0x05`, but I haven't seen something like that. Go look at early versions of MPLAB for PIC maybe, it had a nasty reputation for being non-compliant.