# Odd bit shifting behavior

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, integer-promotion

I have the following C code which works:

```
int ex(unsigned int x) {
    int mask  = 0x55555555;
    int a = ((x >> 0) & mask );
    return a + ((x >> 1) & mask );
}
```

However, when I expand it to this, I get a different result:

```
int ex(unsigned int x) {
    int mask  = 0x55555555;
    int a = ((x >> 0) & mask );
    int b = ((x >> 1) & mask );
    return a + b;
}
```

What is the reason for this difference?

EDIT:
Note, I'm compiling this for 32bit.

Comment: Always use unsigned types for bit operations.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, on what platform + compiler does this actually fail for you, and how? Because [I see no difference on GCC / x86-32](https://tio.run/##tVDLboMwELznK7ZUqYyACBL11MIntD/Qi7F5rAomwrhFqvj1ujaYhFx6yx4se2dmZ9YsqhjT@hEFaxQv4FUOHLtDne1QDFCMCVFCYiUKDrYx@vCzA1P20VL5CZBCPD67erlg1PQJGSHLIPbhaeH6C94Xg@qFoQQrJdlSJmd9vIO1xfMrnvwTLV@TtBQFkK8O@ZrgJhfaGIuad46wjWL/EP1wtrVLobOaOSUQCg8p5P5GaevcG31JPKveK@Ocwp5bph1xaXwILwQMgc5nvpm8WSa5dqf5NsF3jU0BJAjQjoyd7qwGSby3DlqULR1YDWWnBD94t59jlp20/mVlQyupo/Z01NH76Q8) (unless I add `-ftrapv`, which makes the second code crash due to overflow as expected).

Comment: (The second version does, of course, invoke undefined behavior if the addition overflows. But at a glance it seems to me that, to actually get the second function to behave differently from the first in practice, you'd probably either need to find a platform where signed integer addition doesn't wrap by default, or else somehow get the compiler to inline the function and then make some unexpected optimization based on the assumption that the addition won't overflow. Which presumably would depend strongly on the actual calling code; hence my curiosity.)

Comment: This is a simplified snippet of code from a larger function. You're right, on my platform, these two snippets behave identically, but in the full function, the implicit type conversion issue pops up.

Comment: What do you mean with "different results"? What are the results, with what values passed as `x`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> What is the reason for this difference?

The 1<sup>st</sup> snippet returns the result of adding two `unsigned`s with the result being (implicitly) converted to an `int`.

The 2<sup>nd</sup> snippet returns the result of adding two `int`s .

---

More on "*The Usual Arithmetic Conversions*":

- [Usual arithmetic conversions in C : Whats the rationale behind this particular rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8937676/694576)
- [C usual arithmetic conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7544123/694576)
- [Implicit integer type conversion in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32364817/694576)